# Why the corresponding between an intrinsic spanning set (or canonical co-ordinate system) and a subspace is continuous?

Tags: differential-geometry, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Consider a line $L(\theta)=t(cos(\theta), sin(\theta)), t\in \mathbb{R}$, then $v(\theta)=\left( \begin{array}{cc} cos(\theta) \\ sin(\theta)\end{array}\right)$ is an extrinsic basis of the line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the correspondence $\theta \to v(\theta)$ is discontinuous.

While taking an intrinsic spanning set $B(\theta)=\left\lbrace cos(\theta)\left( \begin{array}{cc} cos(\theta) \\ sin(\theta)\end{array}\right) , sin(\theta)\left( \begin{array}{cc} cos(\theta) \\ sin(\theta)\end{array}\right)\right\rbrace$ for canonical co-ordinate system of the line, then the correspondence $\theta \to B(\theta)$ is continuous.

Comment: The latter is far from a basis!

Comment: Yea second one is not a basis but I mentioned it from instrinsic perspective as an overdetermined basis.

Comment: Then call it a spanning set, not something it is not. I still would like to see a well-formed question.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question again. I should consider $B(\theta)$ as an overdetermined spanning set.

Comment: So you still don't have a well-formed question. Is it this: If I take an arbitrary (continuous) family of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$, i.e., a topological submanifold of the Grassmannian, is there always a global continuous set of spanning vectors?